# Set default profile picture for parse signup

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to set default profile picture at signup time in parse.the picture is in my project folder. Is there any way to set it without photo upload.

```
var user = new Parse.User();
user.set("username", $('#username').val());
user.set("password", $('#password').val());
user.set("email", $('#email').val());
user.set("phone", $('#phone').val());
user.set("address", $('#address').val());
var parseFile = new Parse.File("profile.jpg", fileData, "image/jpg");
parseFile.save().then(function() {
    alert('done')
}, function(error) {
    alert(error.code);
});
user.set("image", parseFile);

user.signUp(null, {
    success: function(user) {
        alert("successfully insert")
    },
    error: function(user, error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Also, i have tried by creating object.But i am facing problem in data fetch and update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Parse Config** and **Cloud Code** for this purpose.
Upload a default profile picture to a Config field called: defaultProfilePicture.

Then use this in **Cloud Code**:

`Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function (request, response) {
    //check if user being saved has profile picture.
    if (!request.object.has("profilePicture")) {
        Parse.Config.get().then(function(config) {
            request.object.set("profilePicture", config.get("defaultProfilePicture"));
            response.success();
        });
    } else {
        response.success();
    }
});`

http://blog.parse.com/2014/09/08/announcing-parse-config/

Comment: when running your code, the `function(config)` is never called.. if I add a `,function(error){}` after I can see it's always erroring ` {code: undefined, message: 'unauthorized' }` any idea?