# Can't figure out Parse Config with Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, android, parsing, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Been searching for solutions for hours and getting close to no luck. I just don't see much documentation on the matter of Parse Config. At least with solutions because I tried everything I could find.

So basically I'm trying to set a default picture when someone saves an object with a status as "denied."

It started with me looking at this: [Set default profile picture for parse signup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633360/set-default-profile-picture-for-parse-signup)

And here's what I got.

```
//Accepts/denies picture request
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Requests", function(request) {
 
  var toUserId = request.object.get("to").id;
  var fromUserId = request.object.get("from").id;
  var toUser = null;
  var fromUser = null;
 
  var status = request.object.get("status");
 
    if (status === "accepted") {        
      .....
 
  } else if (status === "denied") {

    
    Parse.Config.get().then(function(config) { 

        request.object.set('photo', config.get("denied"));
    }).then(function() {
        console.log('Success: Denied photo set.');
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('error: denied photo not set');
    });
    

  } else if (status === "waiting") {
     ....
       
  }
});
```

I get a success everytime, but I get nothing as the photo file. I'm stuck and not sure what else to do here. The status changes to denied correctly, but I don't get anything to show up as a file in the photo spot, stays as undefined..

```
I2015-08-24T01:54:09.837Z]v46 after_save triggered for Requests for user oE3FhNfyWW:

  Input: {"object":{"createdAt":"2015-08-24T01:54:03.398Z","from":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"odv4R9OWso"},"objectId":"InB8Iods8U","status":"denied","to":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"oE3FhNfyWW"},"updatedAt":"2015-08-24T01:54:09.834Z"}}
  Result: Success
I2015-08-24T01:54:09.973Z]Success: Denied photo set.
```

Comment: did you find a solution. I'm having the exact same issue. I though it was an issue with initializing Parse with `Parse.initialize(client, key)` but I'm still having the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice the code doesn't say `request.object.save()`, which might explain why the object isn't changed when you check later on.

But saving seems strange, since this function runs *after saving*. That's either wasteful or infinitely-loopy.  Since the goal is to modify request.object (the object just saved), then do this on `beforeSave()`.

Remember to call `response.success()` or `.error()` at the end of `beforeSave()`.

Comment: No, because the next thing that happens after beforeSave is the request.object gets saved.

Comment: Before/after save are just like any other cloud functions, so its fine to run any logic in them that you need.  The only ill-advised call in those is save() on the request.object.